# How do i append a new text at JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

I read, some StackOverflow questions that I need to use `HTML` stuffs.
But what would be the easiest it without any of `HTML` stuff.

**Here's the code**

```
label.setText(label.getText() + (String)boxTimes.getSelectedItem() + input);
```

This code will produce this

[image]

What I want is:

[image]

Comment: As I understood you want a label with border around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must know a bit of basic `String` format:

- `\n` line break
- `\t` tab

So your code will be like:

```
String myLabel = 
      // 4
      label.getText() + "\n\n" + 
      // 7:00
      (String)boxTimes.getSelectedItem() + "\t" +
      // - Going out....
      "- " + input;

label.setText(myLabel);
```

But as long as `JLabel` **does not accept `\n`** as [Abishek Manoharan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2775450/abishek-manoharan) pointed, you must use `<br>`.

```
String  myLabel = 
    "<html>" + 
        label.getText() + 
        "<br/><br/>" +
        (String)boxTimes.getSelectedItem() + " - " + input + 
    "</html>;

label.setText(myLabel);
```

Comment: I guess a JLabel ignores "\n" since it expects HTML markup.

Comment: Thank you so much, I still need to use the html though, since that's the only solution

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with the same problem too and couldn't find a viable solution.
So I went ahead and used a `JTextArea` instead of `JLabel`.

```
JTextArea label = new JTextArea();
label.setEditable(false);
label.setBackground(null);
```

1. It gives the same look and feel of a `JLabel`
2. You can use '\n' and '\t' as you like,
3. and what more, **the text is selectable** which is not possible in JLabel.